# Is there a way to configure elasticsearch default index creation to treat array objects as type nested?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use elasticsearch auto index creation, for my complex types but It wants to treat my list items as normal objects rather then a nested type is there a simple way to change this default?

Comment: You can achieve what i think you want to achieve using templates but could you elaborate more on what it is exactly that you want and why you want it?

Comment: I have some collections that need to be treated as sub documents.  I wanted to setup some type of naming convention so that when I name a collection List_*** elasticsearch would create the type as nested.

Comment: Ahh ok then I understood the q correctly :) will try to andwer later tonight.